# Get rid of unicode characters in VSCode Interactive Python Environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode `Version: 1.46.1` on Mac OS Catalina.  I'm using the built-in Python interactive terminal `Python 3.7.4` Whenever I print strings, it shows up with unicode, making it difficult to read, like so:

```
\\u201cI like what we have.\\u201d It is quiet and there is somebody else in the room. I tell my dog that I need to go and he says, \\u201cjust alright.\\u201d ~~I am hungry.\\n\\n
```

I have tried every flavor of un-escaping escaped characters.  See here:

[Unescaping escaped characters in a string using Python 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339630/unescaping-escaped-characters-in-a-string-using-python-3-2)

And

[Using unicode character u201c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281774/using-unicode-character-u201c)

But to no avail.  I think the problem lies in the encoding options built into VSCode itself, but I'm not sure how to modify that.

Comment: what code do you use to print it?

Comment: as for me there is no sense to unescape it because `print()` create unesaped code. Do you have this problem without VSCode? If you have problem only with VSCode then you will have to search solution in VSCode and maybe search on some forum for `VSCode` - they should know more about `VSCode`. And maybe they already had this problem and resolved it.

Comment: An example would really help. Also does this repro with same python code in the terminal? It might be our encoding of the output is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780380/how-to-print-the-right-character-from-unicode-like-u201c%E5%80%9F-u201d%E4%B8%9C%E9%A3%8E-in-python/55780454) page could provide some information for you.

"\u201c" and "\u201d" means “ and ”, but they will not work, they should be "\u201c" and "\u201d".